# How to recover a deleted save file in Pokemon Gold Virtual Console?

Tags: pokemon-series, virtual-console, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I deleted my save file by mistake. Is there a way to recover it? I haven't started a new game yet.

Answer (score 1):

Once a save file is deleted, there is no way to recover it.